# JPA OneToOneToOne mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I just got started with the Java Persistence API, and am getting comfortable using it. However, I ran into a little design decision.

Let's say I run a car rental shop, with several cars, several customers, and different customers can use different cars. For storing the favorite cars of a customer, I would use a @OneToMany relationship from the customer class, and for the customer presently renting a car, a @OneToOne from the car class.

Now, how should I store the number of kilometers that a customer drove with a given car? With a MySQL database, for instance, I would create a table with three (four with id) columns : customer_id, car_id, and kilometers. customer_id and car_id would be FKs, and kilometers... is self-explanatory.

What is the best approach with JPA? I could store, for instance from the customer's class, a @OneToMany object, like a list of pair. The first would be the car, the second the number of kilometers that the customer drove with that car. But that doesn't feel right. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have an entity named RentalCarMileage like this:

```
@Entity
public class RentalCarMileage implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Car car;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal mileage;
}

@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<RentalCarMileage> rentals;

}

@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private List<RentalCarMileage> rentals;

}
```

This mapping assumes you want to have a bi-directional association but the @OneToMany is not mandatory. You can simply run queries to get the rentals of a Car or a Customer.

Comment: Well, thank you! It sure is much better than what I came up with.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `@ManyToMany` annotation.
E.g.:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( name="INTERMEDIATE_TABLE_NAME",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="customer_id_name")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "car_id_name")})
Set<Car> cars;
```

in `Customer` class, or the inverse, in the `Car` class

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the actual number of kilometers are stored...?

Comment: My bad. I forgot that you needed to add the kilometers information. Use @VladMihalcea answer, instead.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I was hoping you were using some neat trick I didn't spot, and that everything would work with two annotations and one field.